# Could not install pycocotools in windows: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory error:

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, object-detection, pycocotools

I'm new to machine learning and have started with a windows 8.1 pc having GeForce GTX 540M. I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) to get started with the object detection models. I built my own dataset and tried to train it as per the tutorial but with "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17" model. But could not perform it successfully as i had troubles with the "train.py" file given in the tutorial.

So I googled and found that we have to use "model_main.py" to train the model. While trying to train using "model_main.py" I got this error:
`"ImportModuleError: No module named 'pycocotools' was found"`

So I tried to install the cocoapi from this [link](https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi) . I followed the instructions as given, but got stuck with the error shown below, I've tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
Collecting git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
  Cloning https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git to c:\users\home\appdata\l
ocal\temp\pip-req-build-76t4e6ys
Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycocotools ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-76t4e6ys\\PythonAPI\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4_r37hm6 --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycocotools
  running build_ext
  building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pycocotools
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\common
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c/nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I../common -Ic:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\include -Ic:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" /Tcpycocotools/_mask.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pycocotools/_mask.obj
  _mask.c
  c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pycocotools
  Running setup.py clean for pycocotools
  Complete output from command c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-76t4e6ys\\PythonAPI\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-76t4e6ys\PythonAPI\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
      cythonize(ext_modules)
    File "c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 956, in cythonize
      aliases=aliases)
    File "c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\Cython\Buil
d\Dependencies.py", line 801, in create_extension_list
      for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't ma
tch any files" % filepattern):
    File "c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\Cython\Buil
d\Dependencies.py", line 111, in nonempty
      raise ValueError(error_msg)
  ValueError: 'pycocotools/_mask.pyx' doesn't match any files

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for pycocotools
Failed to build pycocotools
Installing collected packages: pycocotools
  Running setup.py install for pycocotools ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-76t4e6ys\\PythonAPI\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext "-L/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/ucrt" install --record C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ykypadav\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running build_ext
    building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c/nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I../common -Ic:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\include -Ic:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" /Tcpycocotools/_mask.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pycocotools/_mask.obj
    _mask.c
    c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error
 C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit
 status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\home\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe -u -c "import setup
tools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-76t4e6ys\\PythonAPI\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext "-L/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/ucrt" install --record C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ykypadav\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1
in C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-76t4e6ys\PythonAPI

(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error

```
 ValueError: 'pycocotools/_mask.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

So I cloned https://github.com/waleedka/coco to my local device. Then when I was running make I was getting the above error.
the exact command I was running was--

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\coco-master>python3 PythonAPI/setup.py build_ext install
```

I was when I was running above command I got the problem.
Then I found out a solution on the issues page of the same repository. It happens that you have to cd into PythonAPI then run--

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

That solved some problems for me.
Moreover some people were saying they still got problems but when they used python3 instead of python their problem was solved.

Answer (score 10):

easy fix, use `pip install pycocotools-windows`

Answer (score 8):

First install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126 with default selection.
Then,
`pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI`

Answer (score 6):

you can try:

```
pip install pycocotools-windows
```

it's worked for me :) on windows station :

Comment: I am getting an error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycocotools-windows (from versions: none)` on Windows 10, Python 3.9.6, pip 21.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command (it worked for me on Windows 10, Python 3.7.5, and Visual 2017) :

```
pip3 install "git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"
```

(from https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/169#issuecomment-462528628)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this ERROR: `Command errored out with exit status 1` or `2`

Then install this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^subdirectory=PythonAPI
```

Answer (score -1):

pip install pycocotools-windows
worked for me