# VS Code error when importing pycocotools.coco

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, image-processing, coco, pycocotools

I'm trying to use VScode for image processing in Python, I cloned a repo from GitHub to try it out, but code fails at the line `from pycocotools.coco import COCO` .
I Googled it, and installed the Visual C++ Build tools, and cloned the coco github repo (https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi), to install the library.
When running the command `python3 PythonAPI/setup.py build_ext install`
I get another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\barti\OneDrive\Documents\coco\PythonAPI\setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    cythonize(ext_modules)
  File "C:\Users\barti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 970, in cythonize
    module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
  File "C:\Users\barti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 816, in create_extension_list
    for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
  File "C:\Users\barti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 114, in nonempty
    raise ValueError(error_msg)
ValueError: 'pycocotools/_mask.pyx' doesn't match any files.
```

At this point I can't find anything helpful on Google, if anyone has an idea how to solve it, I'm here to listen. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

when you run command:

```
python3 PythonAPI/setup.py build_ext install
```

You should be inside the directory that `setup.py` was in.

I think you can try to install [Visual C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70007787/18359438).

[image]

Comment: I was, and that's the error I got that I posted above

Comment: @vivi25-5 I edit my answer, can visual C++ Build Tools help?